# LDAP Check for person existence in a top level Organization

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I am a starter in LDAP and just learnt in last few days about how to make LDAP queries. I 
used this fragment of code to find the membership of a person in a group.

```
    SearchControls srch = new SearchControls();
    srch.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE); 
    String search_start = "CN=somegroup@myworld.com,OU=Managed Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=americas,DC=myworld,DC=com";
    String[] attrIDs = {"cn"};
    srch.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
    String search_target = "(member=CN=django@myworld.com,OU=US,OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=americas,DC=myworld,DC=com)";
    NamingEnumeration answer = cntxt.search( search_start, search_target,srch );
    boolean isInGroup = false;
    while(answer.hasMore()) {
        SearchResult rslt = (SearchResult)answer.next();
        Attributes attrs = rslt.getAttributes();
        NamingEnumeration<String> all = attrs.getIDs();
        isInGroup = true;
            break; 
    }
```

My task now if to also find if the person belongs to a organization at the top level. I am out of ideas to figure what kind of query can I use in such a case. Can someone provide some advice on this?

regards,
koya

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your top level OU is: `OU=Accounts,DC=americas,DC=myworld,DC=com`

Couldn't you just change the following to achieve what you need?

```
// ...
String search_start = "OU=Accounts,DC=americas,DC=myworld,DC=com";
// ...
String search_target = "(member=CN=django@myworld.com,OU=Accounts,DC=americas,DC=myworld,DC=com)";
// ...
```